# Update Strings.xml from server - Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app in Android SDK(Eclipse) which has Text Views and Buttons. The text inside Text Views and Labels for Buttons come from Strings.xml
I want to update Strings.xml from server, that is if I create new Strings.xml/Data on my Server my App should recognize the changes and download this new Strings.xml/Data in background to overwrite the existing one.
I know that the Server push can be achieved via C2DM, but the part I want to know is that where do I put code in my Java or XML files to tell my App that when ever there is an update available download it from this server address and update the current Strings.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to change the resources of your APK. Another possibility might be to use [Google Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/tagmanager/) for Mobile. You won't be able to add new labels, but you'll be able to change them from a web interface. Every 12h (default) the app checks if there's a new container available and if so, it will download the new container. You can also tell the app to look for a new container, for example on start up of the app. Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av2K5bhF46g) for more information

Comment: I  was about to give same solution, one up from me

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible because once the apk is build we cant change the resources of the application at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your strings from strings.xml dynamicly,not just use its R.id.xxx.  And then download the new Strings.xml from server and update the strings.

Comment: Can you tell me an example of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

**I think the best ways is next :**

**1)** Put your strings information to server. And when you will need an update your text messages - just pulling him from server. This a best way for my mind. Because you will a privilege to **crypt your information.**

**2)** Another way is a update all application. You need a new dev version. Push her to android market and `OS` automatically update him.